# How to make SELECT that "knows" which entity has more elements?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a simple database that has three tables (`company`, `phone`, `email`) which are related through the rules:

- A company may have zero or more phone numbers;
- A company may have zero or more e-mail addresses.

Here is the MySQL code: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fPVftWkd)

---

Let's suppose the following 2 cases:

- A company has 3 phones and 2 e-mails (**case 1**)
- A company has 2 phones and 3 e-mails (**case 2**)

~

I would like to make a SELECT that returns the following:

**Case 1**

```
Company         Phone       E-mail
--------------------------------------------
Test Company    1111222     export@testco.co
Test Company    2222222     import@testco.co
Test Company    3333222 
--------------------------------------------
```

**Case 2**

```
Company         Phone       E-mail
--------------------------------------------
Test Company    1111222     export@testco.co
Test Company    2222222     import@testco.co
Test Company                sales@testco.co
--------------------------------------------
```

---

That SELECT should "know", for a given company, which entity has more elements (`phone` or `email`) and then return a result where *the number of rows is equal to number of elements from the entity with more elements* (`phone` in case 1; `email` in case 2).

I could not figure out how to do that. Here's the best I could do: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/LhNsTPJS)

Comment: just a side note, pastebin is not very useful around here, better include the code into your post directly. But for providing something for us to fiddle around with SQLFiddle is an excellent addendum, I basically just pasted both your pastebins into this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/451f6f/1

Comment: I would not try to do this within MySQL.  I would do it within whatever application is calling your query.  The reason is that you don't have any association between phone numbers and emails, so SQL can't easily work out how to pair them up for display.

Comment: @DavidWallace If that's the best practice/solution, I'll adopt it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I feel that doing it outside SQL is best practice; just for the sake of maintainability.  As Gordon has demonstrated in his rather remarkable answer below, it is possible to do it another way.  But I think Gordon's solution sacrifices some maintainability.  I had to read it three times just to understand how it works.  But I don't see any harm in putting some logic in the application code, rather than the SQL.

Comment: @DavidWallace: "SQL" can work this out without too much trouble. Just no MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e812a/2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I see.  That's ANSI 2003, right?  So I guess it's supported by the majority of "current version" DBMSs.  My fault for learning SQL last century!

Comment: @DavidWallace yes that's ANSI SQL. Would work with Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Teradata, Vertica and probably some more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pain to do in MySQL, but it is possible.  Here is the logic.  Enumerate the values for the emails and phones for each company.  Then aggregate these based on the company and sequence number:

```
select ep.company, min(ep.email) as email, min(ep.phone) as phone
from ((select e.company, e.email, NULL as phone,
              (@rne := if(@company = company, @rne + 1, if(@company := company, 1, 1)) ) as seqnum
       from email e cross join
            (select @rne := 0, @company := '') vars
       order by e.company
      ) union all
      (select p.company, NULL, p.phone,
              (@rnp := if(@companyp = company, @rnp + 1, if(@companyp := company, 1, 1)) ) as seqnum
       from phone p cross join
            (select @rnp := 0, @companyp := '') vars
       order by p.company
      )
     ) ep
group by ep.company, ep.seqnum
order b ep.company, ep.seqnum;
```

The expression:

```
 (@rne := if(@company = company, @rne + 1, if(@company := company, 1, 1)) ) as seqnum
```

for setting `seqnum` is a way of safely using the variables in MySQL.  Note that MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a select, so the more natural:

```
 @rne := if(@company = company, @rne + 1, 1), @company := company
```

may not work, because the second would be evaluated first.  This method with the nested assignment doesn't have this problem.